# Code coverage in MVC ASP

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am very new to web development. We are using "visual studio 2012 for web" for developing the web app, and we have developed our appications in MVC pattern using devexpress controls.

Now I have been assigned with the task of finding code coverage for our project and find out the relevant matrix fo the same.

Requesting help on the same as I am very new to these concepts

I searched a lot in net and I found it very complex to digest the materials and tools provided

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, Code Coverage is a measure of how much of your code is tested, or "covered" by unit tests. If you're not doing unit tests, it's meaningless.

If you *are* doing unit tests, it will provide *some* idea as to how effectively you have arranged /designed your code - if you have tons of tests but low coverage, you need to rethink your test approach, for example. If you have tons of actual source code but very few unit tests, it will help you to focus on areas that are more important to test than others.

But be aware that there is no one single rule about having X amount of coverage - 100% is generally not attainable and you have to spend some time with your team and your testers agreeing what % is "good enough".

There are quite a few code coverage tools available; VS Premium has built in code coverage, NCover is good, and my personal favourite, Jetbrain's dotCover, integrates very well with VS, to name but a few.

Comment: Thanx stephen.. Is there any opensource components available for code coverage that could be integarted to VS 2012

Comment: @Robert_Junior yes there is open cover, although I have not used it.http://opencover.codeplex.com/ But do check out dotCover, it's not expensive and really, really good.